# How to change the image on click in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to change the image after clicking the particular row in the table 
in following code I am using ng-repeat.inside table data I used two image tag.
Now my problem is how to show only one image at time and after clicking the table data icon should change to alliterative image but for particular row.
my problem is that when I am altering the image(using ng-show) on click it change all table data image.i want to change particular table data image.
Thanks in advance

```
 <tr  ng-repeat="camName in jsonObj2.body.response.cam" >

                <td     ng-click=checkBoxImage()>
                    <img  ng-src="checkbox_unchecked.png"/>
                    <img  ng-src="checkbox_checked.png"/>
                        {{camName.name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Improve the problem statement. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ngShow and ngHide attributs might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ng-show*** didnt work because it has its own scope and own $animate service. You can use ***ng-if*** for your use, and it shall not update table data.

```
<td     ng-click=checkBoxImage()> //set checked value in the $scope of //controller.js
                    <img  ng-if="checked==false" ng-src="checkbox_unchecked.png"/>
                    <img  ng-if="checked==true" ng-src="checkbox_checked.png"/>
                        {{camName.name}}
                </td>
```

Comment: it will set all rows image to either checked or unchecked...
but i need a particular row which is selected to change the image..

Comment: try using $index to mark the checked images and use the ng-repeat with a ng-if on the jsonObj2.body.response.cam[$index]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead

```
<img ng-src="{{camName.id == 'online_offline' && 'icon1.png' || 'icon2.png'}}"/
```

It will work if  `camName.id` actually has `online_offline` and `online_offline`. I have just assumed the value of `camName.id`

Comment: camera id is integer value..not offline online

Comment: Do you want checkbox in the `<td>` ?